# convert string to int32 while adding datagrid items

Tags: c#, string, datagrid, int

Guys, sorry for the basic question. I try to find out but I still get stuck with it. I am new to programming so, if you guys can help me, it's mean a lot. Thanks.
For this code to i got help from someone in this site.

Here's my problem,I have a .txt data like this

> ```
> 10192 20351 30473 40499 50449 60234 
>
> 10192 20207 30206 40203 50205 60226 
>
> 10192 20252 30312 40376 50334 60252
> ```

And this is my code, where I open the text file and parsing into numbers and put it to 6 columns datagrid.

So my data turns out like this in datagrid:

Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|Column 6

10192  | 20351|   30473  | 40499  | 50449  | 60234

```
private void Parsing_String(string filename)
    {
        List<Row> list = new List<Row>();
       
        foreach (String str in File.ReadLines(filename))
        {
            String[] strCols = str.Split(Convert.ToChar(" "));
            list.Add(new Row()
            {
                Column1 = strCols[0].Substring(2),
                Column2 = strCols[1].Substring(2),
                Column3 = strCols[2].Substring(2),
                Column4 = strCols[3].Substring(2),
                Column5 = strCols[4].Substring(2),
                Column6 = strCols[5].Substring(2),
            });
        }

        

        dg.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Column4 { get; set; }
        public string Column5 { get; set; }
        public string Column6 { get; set; }
       
    }
```

What I want to do is, I need the numbers sequentially row by row to put in some mathematics equation. And I need to convert the string into int. But I don't know how, I put some trial but failed.

for example:
first I put first line of rows in datagrid which contain 6 group of number and calculate it. Next, the second row. and so on. How can I get the number that i want and put it in mathematics equation.

Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take [flq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51428/flq)'s example a little farther, I wouldn't count on the data and would do something like this so if the parse fails you get a 0 - unless you want to catch the exception and handle it differently.

```
int outValue;
list.Add(new Row()
            {
                Column1 = int.TryParse(strCols[0].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0;,
                 ...
```

Comment: thanks, but how about my substring? i cant use with int.tryparse

Comment: this won't work? Column1 = int.TryParse(strCols[0].Substring(2), out outValue) ? outValue : 0;,

Comment: yes it works, thanks, now value in Column1 should be int right? not string anymore?

Comment: yes, you end up with ints as data type of the Column... Properties

Answer (score 1):

If you use the data for binding, there shouldn't be a problem storing the converted values into the row:

```
list.Add(new Row()
            {
                Column1 = int.Parse(strCols[0]),
                ...
```

Whatever UI stuff you put on top, it will call ToSTring() on it anyway and display the thing as string. Consequently, your row object has 6 ints.

On a minor note, in C# you can denote a char with single quotes, the split then becomes : `str.Split(' ')`

For more elegance, you can have the line interpretation inside your Row object by passing a single line of the file into the constructor and performing the split in the constructor. Then you can make the setters on row private. The foreach loop then becomes:

```
dg.ItemsSource = File.ReadLines(filename).Select(line => new Row(line)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks man. str.Split(' ') is use for a white-space right? it works then. but waht about my Substring? it cant work with int.Parse.

Comment: new Row(line) what line? is this code can give me an independent access to each cell?

Comment: single quotes denote a char, e.g. 'a' . I don't know what is with your substring, but you can try and parse any string. The numbers in your example are parsable. If it doesn't parse a FormatException is thrown. INspect the string you passed in to Parse.  "Select" is a so-called higher-order function,look it up. It operates over an enumeration of e.g. strings. "line" is a variable in the scope of Select, but I think you should skip that part and carry on with what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) to convert the strings to int32s.

Comment: He can avoid the overhead of TryParse if he knows everything is in fact a valid integer.